# Obtain Java size of base typed array

Tags: java, types

I have a method:

```
public int getSize(int[][] input);
```

How can I obtain the size of base typed array ? For example we will pass 3x6 array:

```
getSize(new int[3][6]);
```

How can I return the `6` value ?

Comment: If you want to account for "triangular arrays", you'll have to loop over the first dimension and add up the lengths of the component arrays.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, please ? You can simply return `array[0].length`, if I understand correctly..

Comment: If you pass an array, there is no guarantee that the function will not modify it, and not all of the elements may have the same length (even if they all started out at 6).

Comment: @kocko since you don't have 10k rep yet, you can't see that there's a deleted answer providing that code as answer, and the comments there pointing the problems in that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

max size :

```
int max = 0;
for (int[] i : input){
    if (i.length > max){
        max = i.length;
        }
}
```

Switch the > with < to find the min size ;)

this will come into effect when you do something like this :

```
int[][] int2dArr = new int[2][];
int2dArr[0] = new int[10];
int2dArr[1] = new int[11];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have a specific answer. You need to be aware that all the secondary arrays can be different lengths, so array[3].length may not equal array[4].length for example.